# Electron load files in the renderer process

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I wanted to debug some part of an [source code](https://github.com/MbProg/BT) with vscode. But I realized that vscode does not halt at the breakpoints that I insert in the handler argument of the delegate function:

```
graphContainer
    .delegate(
            'g.cluster',
            'click',
            function() {
                // vscode does not halt at breakpoints set here in this function
                editorController.unhighlight();
                editorController.highlightNodeInCode(nodeData[this.id]);
            });
```

When asked in a thread, they answered me that the code is not in the renderer process. The code is in a file called [visualizer.js](https://github.com/MbProg/BT/blob/master/js/views/visualizer.js) which is the javascript part of [visualizer.html](https://github.com/MbProg/BT/blob/master/windows/visualizer.html) in the electron project. So I thought it would be in the renderer process.
Thus, my question is: how do I move this file in the renderer process to be able to debug the code?

Comment: Sure looks like the renderer process from here. Have you tried manually inserting a 'debugger;' command inside this function to see if that works? I've stepped through even Node's internal code in the devtools debugger window. Worst case, you might need to attach a debugger to the main process, which is slightly more advanced, but there are instructions in the Electron documentation to do this.

Comment: Thanks. The debugger command helped me finding out if it works.